# where is B2B extension in Magento 2.2 EE?

Tags: magento2.2, quote, magento2.2.2, magento2-enterprise, b2b

I'm using **Magento 2.2.2 Commerce(EE)**. I refer this **Magento 2.2 B2B** [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/b2b/bk-b2b.html?_ga=2.191132138.1770967340.1518967645-578715442.1499410356) but none of the extension I found by the name **BundleNegotiableQuote, BundleRequisitionList.....etc**.

Also, I heard request quote feature is added in Magento 2.2 but I didn't see any request quote button on the frontend.

Please clarify me.

Thanks.

Comment: have you enabled extension from backend ?

Comment: I'm searching that extensions on vendor/magento/ folder

Comment: how you have installed it - using command line ? or you are finding in default EE setup ?

Comment: I download the archive from Magento my account download page and install by using the command line. It's default Magento 2.2.2 EE with sample data setup

Comment: For b2b - you need to install it separately - after installing magento 2.2 EE - you need to install B2B extension separately.

Comment: do you have any document link?

Comment: yeah sure, please post it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First - you need to install B2B extension for Magento 2.2 EE Separately after installing your magento 2.2 EE.**

**Below is the steps to install the B2B extensions :**

Change to your Magento installation directory and enter the following command to update your composer.json file and install the Magento Commerce for B2B extension:

> **composer require magento/extension-b2b**

When prompted, enter your authentication keys. Your public key is your username; your private key is your password.

Run the following commands after Composer finishes updating modules:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

[Here is the reference link for B2B installation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html)

After successfully installation of B2B extension - **you need to enable it from

> store -> configuration -> general -> B2B features**

**Note : Make sure you add your EE user key and password then and then you will able to install this extensions..**